# Laravel: Which npm packages should be in "dependencies" vs "devDependencies"?

Tags: laravel, npm, dependencies, packages.json

In Laravel 5.3 the package.json file looks as following: all packages are in devDependencies. Do somebody can tell me which packages are needed in production too. I think all except browsersync.

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1", 
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
    "laravel-elixir-browsersync-official": "^1.0.0",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dropzone": "^4.3.0"
  }
}
```

I think some packages like vue.js are also needed in production mode so I would move them to dependencies and not devDependencies.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to use the laravel package in your application or do you want to work on the packge itself? Also which module system are you using for the dependencies (CommonJS, Bower, ...)?

Comment: @BrunoRanschaert I edited my post

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All of those are `devDependencies` if you are using `elixir`:

Firstly, you don't need `elixir` in production because it's just a wrapper for `gulp`, hopefully, you will compile your assets on your development machine and upload them.

All other npm javascript libraries can be compiled with `elixir`, so there is no need to have them on the production machine. By default `elixir` uses `webpack` to compile `resources\assets\js\app.js` into `public\js\app.js` which you need to include in your webpages as a `script`.

If you take a look at: `resources\assets\js\bootstrap.js` you will see the packages that `laravel` adds by default (things like `vue`, `bootstrap` and `jQuery`), so if, for example you want to add `dropzone` to your project you simply add it to `bootstrap.js` like so:

`require('dropzone');`

Which would now compile `dropzone` to `public\js\app.js` making `dropzone` a `devDependency` also.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer now much things are clearer to me :) one additional question... how do I import stylesheets from node_modules folder?

Comment: For stylesheets you just use an `@import` statement in `resources/assets/sass/app.scss`, you can include either `css` or `scss` files (or a folder), you just need to include the entire path from the root of your project e.g. for bootstrap you have `@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";`

Comment: okaay thanks that worked... I had the error to put .css at the end of the path

Comment: Caveat: when using `npm shrinkwrap` to lock down specific package versions (so that you push to prod exactly what you've been working on in dev), by default `devDependencies` are NOT locked down. To do that, use `npm shrinkwrap --dev`.

Answer (score 5):

Also, in newer versions of Laravel that use Laravel Mix (which is a wrapper around Webpack) all your dependencies can be under `devDependencies`.

Webpack compiles everything down to a single file (`/js/app.js`), or multiple files, if for example, you use the `extract` method to build your files (`/js/app.js`, `/js/app.js`, `/js/manifest.js`). And those are the only files your browser needs to execute your JavaScript code; and for Webpack to build them it's enough to find all the dependencies under `devDependencies`.

Comment: What if we DON'T want to install some of these `devDependencies` in production environment? Concretely, I don't want to use both `browser-sync ; browser-sync-webpack-plugin` packages in production because at least one of them sets the cookie `io` that is not wished for the enduser, regarding to GDPR law / spirit.

Comment: Note also that you may be referring to `npm run prod` when saying "Webpack compiles everything down to a single file (/js/app.js),"